# Djando multi-level 'select' field

Tags: python, django

I trying to build multi-level 'select' which is based on 2 models.

First model 'Group'
Second model 'Category'

I want to see 'select' like this:

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

```
self.fields["category"].choices = select
```

I build variable 'select' using next code:

```
group=Group.objects.all()
for i in group:
if len(select)<=0:
    select=[(i.name)]
else:
    select.append(i.name)
for n in Category.objects.filter(maingroup_id=i.id):
    select.append((str(n.id), n.name),)
print(select)
'Swedish Cars', ('volvo', 'Volvo'), ('saab', 'Saab'), 'German Cars',('mercedes', 'Mercedes'), ('audi', 'Audi')
```

But the value in the 'select' variable doesn't work with next code:

```
self.fields["category"].choices = select
```

It work if I create 'select' variable with next values manually:

```
('Swedish Cars', (('volvo', ' Volvo'), ('saab', 'Saab'))),('German Cars', (('mercedes', 'Mercedes'), ('audi', 'Audi')))
```

Comment: Correct your code snippets, inside your selecting build code there is something wrong with indentation, also inside printed result there missing apostrophes/quotes. Without that i'm not sure if your code is wrong or if you just didn't paste it here correctly

Comment: I corrected apostrophes/quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at list that was generated by your code and list that you've provided by hand, there are some differences.

this is generated by your code, separated into new lines after each top-level element:

```
[
    'Swedish Cars',
    ('volvo', 'Volvo'),
    ('saab', 'Saab'),
    'German Cars',
    ('mercedes', 'Mercedes'),
    ('audi', 'Audi'),
]
```

And this is provided by you by hand:

```
[
    ('Swedish Cars', (('volvo', ' Volvo'), ('saab', 'Saab'))),
    ('German Cars', (('mercedes', 'Mercedes'), ('audi', 'Audi'))),
]
```

As you can see, correct list contains only 2 top-level elements, but your code is generating list with six elements. On top level there should be only 2-tuple elements, where first element of that tuple is label for group, and second contains list of sub-elements. List of sub-elements also should contain only 2-tuple elements, where first element of that tuples should be value for your choice and second, label for that value.

Corrected code:

```
group=Group.objects.all()
select = []
for i in group:
    subgroup = []
    for n in Category.objects.filter(maingroup_id=i.id):
        subgroup.append((str(n.id), n.name))

    select.append(group.name, subgroup)
```

or more pythonic version:

```
select = [(g.name, [(n.id, n.name) for n in Category.objects.filter(maingroup_id=group.id)]) for g in Group.objects.all()]
```